# Creating new UIElements via commands

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Is there a simple way to do this?

My problem is mostly that the user triggers the element creation via a context menu on on control, and then wants to create a copy, or a new element nearby and the like.

I cannot seem to find a way to pass the appropriate information to the `Execute` function.

I know about `CommandParameter` but my gut feeling is to pass the entirety of the source control (or its parent in the case of the right click menu) and that seems wrong.

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Ideally you don't create/duplicate controls. You create/duplicate underlying VM and the control is created simply by binding ...

Comment: @Didier so when someone selects copy control, what actually happens? How can I get the VM associated with that control to duplicate it?

Answer (score 2):

What level of duplication are you talking about?

The easiest case:

1) `IEumerable<object>` in your ViewModel, with different ViewModels(IFunnyControlViewModel, ISadCotrolViewModel), etc..

2) Create ItemsControl in View and bind against that collection. You can use DataTemplates to "map" different viewmodel to different view control.

3) Receive ViewModel Execute() with underlying ViewModel, just "re-add" it to the collection, thus "referencing" the same object, if you want to keep them synchroized, or clone it.

```
public YourViewModel {
   public IEnumerable<YourBaseControlViewModel> Controls {get; set;}

   public YourViewModel()
   {
       Controls = new List<YourBaseControlViewModel();
       Controls.Add(new YourFunnyControlViewModel());
   }

   // Called from View by Command.
   public void DuplicateControl(YourBaseControlViewModel Control)
   {

      // either duplicate it using cloning, or add the same reference.
      Controls.Add(Control);

   }
}
```

And within ItemsControl, something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
   <ItemsControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Type="{x:Type blah:YourFunnyControlViewModel}">
        custom stuff here
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: So to be clear, 1) is have a nested viewmodel structure, with one "master" and the rest "components", 2) Can you expand on this one more? 3) Re-add it to the collection you created in 1?